# laptop second hdd in caddy does not show in bios but shows up after ubuntu boots

Tags: hard-disk, bios, hardware-compatibility

I have installed a second HDD in my notebook via a DVD-HDD caddy. My laptop is a `Lenovo Ideapad 110 15ISK`
I want to dual boot Ubuntu (primary SSD) with Fedora (caddy HDD).

**My observations:**

1. caddy with HDD does not show in bios
2. `ls` on grub command line shows only primary SSD
3. when Ubuntu boots second HDD is detected and shown in file system. I can also see it in Disks and gparted
4. If I reinsert the original DVD drive, it is properly detected in bios
5. I ran `update-grub2`and it detected the Fedora installation and added it as an entry in grub menu list, which I can see at boot also. Selecting the Fedora entry gives an error saying the hard drive is not present

I saw posts on Stackexchange and changed BIOS settings to disable secure boot. Changed boot to Legacy mode, boot priority is legacy first, reset settings to default. None of these detected the HDD.

Fedora installation was done on this same laptop.

Is the problem of not detecting the caddy HDD BIOS related or is the caddy faulty?

Comment: It is possible that booting from the second HDD is not supported on your notebook. You could try updating your BIOS.

Comment: Which partition you use in the external hdd? Mbr or gpt?

Comment: @mashuptwice - even in that case, bios should detect it, isn't it.

Comment: @K-att - it is still an internal hdd and using gtp

Comment: @RahulJadhav no, in that case the BIOS wouldn't be aware of the device as there are no drivers for it in the firmware. If you are using a HDD caddy which gets installed in the DVD drive slot, there should be a small switch to adapt the operating mode to different manufacturers notebooks. Refer to the manual of your actual device.

Comment: Thank you @mashuptwice that clarifies my doubt. Much appreciated.